# updating NSProgressIndicator in elCapitan

Tags: objective-c, osx-elcapitan

updating NSProgressIndicator doesn't work any more in el Capitan. Used to before.
Did you also notice it ? Here is an example of my code. There is also a NSTextfield should contain the incremented value, which is not updated either. You only get the final image at the end of the loop. I filled a bug report to Apple...

AppDelegate.h file

```
 #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

 @interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>{


 IBOutlet NSProgressIndicator * indicateurDeRecherche1;
 IBOutlet NSProgressIndicator * indicateurDeRecherche2;
 IBOutlet NSTextField * textValeur;

  }




   - (IBAction)demarre:(id)sender;
   @end
```

AppDelegate.m file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
// Insert code here to initialize your application
}

  - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
  // Insert code here to tear down your application
}



  - (IBAction)demarre:(id)sender{

   NSLog(@"Demarre");

   [indicateurDeRecherche1 setMaxValue:100];
   [indicateurDeRecherche1 startAnimation:self];

   [indicateurDeRecherche2 setMaxValue:100];
   [indicateurDeRecherche2 startAnimation:self];

   [indicateurDeRecherche1 setDoubleValue:0.0];
   [indicateurDeRecherche2 setDoubleValue:0.0];


    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

    [indicateurDeRecherche1 setDoubleValue:(double)i/200.0];
    [indicateurDeRecherche1 displayIfNeeded];
    [indicateurDeRecherche2 setDoubleValue:(double)i/200.0];
    [indicateurDeRecherche2 displayIfNeeded];
    [indicateurDeRecherche1 needsDisplay];
    //NSLog(@"increment %i",i);
    NSString * valeurIncrement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i/100];
    [textValeur setStringValue:valeurIncrement];

    }

    [indicateurDeRecherche1 stopAnimation:self];
    [indicateurDeRecherche2 stopAnimation:self];
    NSLog(@"Demarre fin");
     }

    @end
```